# can grass gis module be used in parallel mode

Tags: grass-gis, parallel

i want to use my customized grass gis(6.4.3) module for separate bands of a sensor in a parallel mode. is it possible? i have created separate location and if one band is executed ,for the second band message appears as " not found".I searched in the grass manual and seen "GIS_LOCK" variable. can any one suggest me how to use this for my executable in parallel mode.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, GRASS GIS can be used in parallel mode. I would suggest that you review the detailed GRASS Wiki page on [Parallel GRASS Job](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Parallel_GRASS_jobs) as well as the discussion on [OpenMP](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/OpenMP).

There is also some interesting reading (and further links) on parallel grass jobs [here](https://research.csc.fi/supercomputers-and-gis).